# Android inflater exception FileNotFound

Tags: java, android

After I installed ACRA I started to get all kinds of crash reports. Most makes sense and I fix them as I go. But this one doesn't make much sense to me.

1. This is version running on hundreds of devices - this error happened on this device multiple times within time period and now seems to be fine.
2. I can't reproduce it.
3. res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png indeed exists.
4. This is "glitch" type of exception, but I wonder if there any way to handle this one and maybe someone else see this stack trace different.

EDIT:

I have 2 constructors (not sure how to debug those)

```
public TireView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;

        inflateLayout();
    }

    public TireView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;

        inflateLayout();

        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.TireView);

        int i = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TireView_Number, -1);
        if (i != -1)
        {
            setNumber(i);
        }

        i = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TireView_Depth, -1);
        if (i != -1)
        {
            setDepth(i);
        }

        i = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TireView_Pressure, -1);
        if (i != -1)
        {
            setPressure(i);
        }

    }
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.idatt/com.idatt.activities.TrailerInspectionActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error
>   inflating class com.idatt.views.TireView        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error
>   inflating class com.idatt.views.TireView        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:226)
>   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)        at
>   com.idatt.activities.TrailerInspectionActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:279)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   ... 11 moreCaused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
>   ... 26 moreCaused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   File res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02002a 
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
>   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.a(SourceFile:65)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.(SourceFile:38)        ... 29
>   moreCaused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png        at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
>   at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
>   ... 33 moreandroid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86:
>   Error inflating class com.idatt.views.TireView        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:226)
>   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)        at
>   com.idatt.activities.TrailerInspectionActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:279)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
>   ... 26 moreCaused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   File res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02002a 
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
>   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.a(SourceFile:65)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.(SourceFile:38)        ... 29
>   moreCaused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png        at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
>   at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
>   ... 33 morejava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:226)
>   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)        at
>   com.idatt.activities.TrailerInspectionActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:279)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02002a
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
>   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.a(SourceFile:65)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.(SourceFile:38)        ... 29
>   moreCaused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png        at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
>   at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
>   ... 33 moreandroid.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02002a
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
>   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.a(SourceFile:65)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.(SourceFile:38)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:226)
>   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)        at
>   com.idatt.activities.TrailerInspectionActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:279)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png        at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
>   at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
>   ... 33 morejava.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/tire.png
>   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method) 
>   at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
>   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.a(SourceFile:65)        at
>   com.idatt.views.TireView.(SourceFile:38)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:226)
>   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)        at
>   com.idatt.activities.TrailerInspectionActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:279)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: first of all, there is something wrong with `com.idatt.views.TireView`. Check that out first.

Comment: how ever you copy&paste your stacktrace into this question, please never ever do it this way again. It is a pain to read this log... use `adb logcat` and copy that... just as a tip for the next question...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I can't use logcat because this is stack trace from actual device sent via ACRA. I can't reproduce this issue

Comment: @jtanveer I'm not sure what to check. Like I said, it works good 99% of cases. TireView is my custom `LinearLayout` that I use inside my main activity(`TrailerInspectionActivity`)

Comment: does it have the constructors like `public TireView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` and `public TireView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)`?

Comment: I edited to include those 2 constructors that I have